# Rails 3 - Nested Resources & Members/Collections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, dry

Is there a way to avoid having to do this...

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children do
    collection do
      get "/search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format", :action => "search", :constraints => { :term => /\w+/, :offset => /\d+/, :limit => /\d+/ }
    end
  end
end

resources :children do
  collection do
    get "/search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format", :action => "search", :constraints => { :term => /\w+/, :offset => /\d+/, :limit => /\d+/ }
  end
end
```

I thought it would be possible to just do this...

```
resources :parents do
  resources :children do
end

resources :children do
  collection do
    get "/search/:term/:offset/:limit.:format", :action => "search", :constraints => { :term => /\w+/, :offset => /\d+/, :limit => /\d+/ }
  end
end
```

The reason being is I want to be able to use both of these routes...

```
/children/search/term/0/10
/parents/1/children/search/term/0/10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to do the trick

```
def define_children 
  resources :children do
    collection do
      get :search
    end
  end
end

define_children
resources :parents do
  define_children
end
```

`:parent_id` will be set in `params` if the route through `parent` has been used. Otherwise it won't be present. I have omitted constraints for clarity. Also you probably should make the `.format` optional.

Comment: Seems like the best way. You can still have your resources and all that, but throwing in this route gives you the functionality for your resources and keeps things clean.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough.  I'm trying to make it so all the children actions are available to me by simply managing the children resources section.  I don't want to have to declare it twice.  The match doesn't help me with that.  I don't want to have to declare the actions within the children resource for searching and the parent resource as well.

Comment: I have changed my solution - I think this one meets your criteria

Comment: That's a pretty slick idea.  I'll give it a try and if it works I'll be back to award you credit.  Thanks!